# Can one copy some applications from one volume to another on the same iMac(Ventura)?

Tags: hard-drive, applications, imac, ssd, copy-paste

I have a 2015 iMac with an internal hard drive and an external SSD drive attached permanently to it.

I would like to *copy* some
Applications from one drive to another instead of re-installing. I wonder if this is possible, and if so, how to proceed with or without CCC.

Comment: Is the external drive copy a new boot disk so you will be copying to its `/Applications`?   Or do you want to move them to the external and run them from the external presumably to save space on the internal disk? If the latter, this question really is a duplicate (see some of the "related" links).

Comment: What is CCC? Carbon Copy Cloner?

Answer (score 0):

##### TL;DR

Yes.

Install a new OS on a clean partition on a secondary drive (i.e. the external SSD), then copy the applications from the old Applications folder to the Applications folder on the new installation.

---

##### Drag and drop installation

Most applications (if not all) which are installed by simply dragging and dropping can be copied to *any* folder (be that on another, external disk or the internal disk) and run from there - check it yourself.

Seeing as external hard disks are treated as directories, by the OS, once they are mounted, this means you can run the Application from virtually anywhere that is currently mounted.

Notes:

- If you run an application from a non-standard location, i.e. a directory other than the Applications folder, you may find that some applications may moan and pop up a dialog stating that they should be run from the current "official" Applications folder of the currently running OS, but usually that can be ignored.
- If you upgrade your OS to a later version, you may find that some applications stop working, due to incompatabilities - even if you are able to successfully copy them over to your new installation. For example, if you moved from Mojave (or earlier) to Catalina (or later), you will find that the 32 bit versions of applications no longer work, as Catalina dropped support for 32 bit applications.

##### Installation from package

However, applications installed using a package (i.e. by opening a `.pkg` file) can not be *easily* moved or copied<sup>1</sup>, and it is best to re-install these correctly (using the package) on the new OS drive.

[image: package icon]

---

##### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This is because packages usually install various (and possibly numerous) files in multiple places and without carefully examining the install log file, it is a  pain to move all of the individual files in their disparate places, to the corresponding location on the new installation.